# Generate XML Error: Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, sax

So i am trying to generate an invoice xml document from my database by clicking a button in windows form using SAX, however i keep getting the error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." I am unsure of what is wrong. Here are the codes with the problems:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsJdG.png

```
var productID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
var productName = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

 wrt.WriteElementString("ItemID",productID);
 wrt.WriteElementString("ItemName", productName);
```

Comment: When is the error occurring?  Is it in any events?  I've seen errors like this in forms when the control is being constructed.  A DGV rows is initially set to -1 until columns are added and then set to 0.  This change causes DGV events to get called.  So in the events to prevent exceptions you must test to see if the number of rows > 0.

Comment: @jdweng The error occurs at the var productID = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

Comment: @jdweng Err i dont really understand what do you mean by testing to see if the number of rows>0?

Comment: In that line either SelectedRows.Length == 0 or SelectedRows[0].Cells.Length == 0. Use the debugger to inspect the Length property of those collections.

Comment: @rene Is there a way to check a length other than using debugger? I am not experienced in debugging:(

Comment: It is time to be become experienced then. 80% of your working career as a developer you'll spend in the debugger... Just put your cursor on that line and press F9, then hit F5, navigate your app so you'll reach that line. The debugger wil break, hover over the variables to see it's values or use any of the auto-locals or watch windows.

Comment: @rene alright i have done that but how do i see the output and know which part has gone wrong?

Comment: Somewhere not shown in your code here either SelectedRows have not been selected or the rows have no cells. I have no magic ball and your laptop refuses to enable its screen sharing so I can't see what went wrong before you reached those lines. But now that you mastered debugging, the fun starts. Work your way back until you'll find where your assumptions went wrong. Use the F9 trick on each line you expect to be the culprit. Happy debugging....

Comment: Watch that and learn: https://youtu.be/C0vDKXIq_9A?t=245 don't be confused by it being for VS2010, Not much changed over the years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> IndexOutOfRangeException occurs when you are trying to access elements that are not within the range or count of the array in question. For example, if your array has 3 elements at all, accessing the fourth item will always fail.

In regards to your question, there are a couple of scenarios that might result in this type of error.

1. Trying to access `selectedRows` when you have not selected any row in the grid. Confirm that a user has selected items in the grid before continuing.

   2. When a row is selected, the resultant cells of that selectedRow may not be known and thus such approach may not work

I would propose this solution.

```
if(dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Length > 0)
    {
        //get all selected rows
        var rows = dataGridView1.SelectedRows;

        if(rows.Length > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length; i++)
            {
                //get cells in individual columns
                var cells = rows[i].Cells;

                if(cells.Length > 0)
                {
                    //productId in cell 1
                    var productId = cells[0].Value.ToString();

                    //product name in cell 2
                    var productName = cells[1].Value.ToString();

                    wrt.WriteElementString("ItemID",productId);
                    wrt.WriteElementString("ItemName", productName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.